# RHEL resolv.conf search domains ordering constraints?

Tags: domain-name-system, redhat, resolv.conf

I can't seem to find anything (Google, man pages) on what the order of the search line should be used when searching for a host against DNS with multiple levels of subdomains.

host and dig work properly and will work regardless, however when attempting to ping or ssh to a host only the first domain is searched *if* it is the higher level subdomain.

So the below does not work when pinging, only looking up server.internal.company.com and not server.yyz.internal.company.com

```
search internal.company.com yyz.internal.company.com
```

however if these are swapped like below the resolution will work for both `server` and `server.yyz`

```
search yyz.internal.company.com internal.company.com
```

So my question is, is this a bug or did I miss something in documentation/RFC that specifies the order that the search domains should be in?

Comment: You say that it "doesn't work", what specifically happens? For instance, what result do you get with `getent ahosts foo` (foo being some non-qualified name that should resolve)? Also, just to make sure, there are no wildcards involved (that really messes with a lot of stuff, `search` included)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments. By "doesn't work" i mean the expected resolution of the hostname does not return a result. tcpdump shows only one lookup against the higher level domain, and never the subdomain when in the faulted order.

Comment: resolv.conf contains 2 lines, the dns server and the search line of `search internal.company.com yyz.internal.company.com` no wildcards. When i run `getent ahosts foo` in this configuration the result is blank, return code 2. `getent ahosts foo.yyz` will return the expected lookup result. swap the search line around so it is `search yyz.internal.company.com internal.company.com` and the getent response for `foo` and `foo.yyz` return as expected.